# Need alternatives to WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, portability

Because of my [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471904/is-there-an-easier-way-to-learn-programming-for-windows) that was closed, here's a different approach to the same question.

I have found that trying to learn winAPI is difficult and isn't required most of the time to be able to take advantage of native features (thanks to [Spook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471904/is-there-an-easier-way-to-learn-programming-for-windows#comment21896688_15471904))  and now I need a different approach.

I prefer C++ and have a little experience with Qt, but because I'd like to [take advantage of platform specific features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784634/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-using-a-cross-platform-framework-to-develop-for-on), Qt is not a viable solution.

I also care about portability and so .NET might not be viable unless there is a way to use local resources instead of the ones included in the .net framework installer.

So please **enumerate** alternatives which I can start studying to be able to do these things.

For example if I were to make something that uses aero transparency like [this](http://2010.thirteen23.com/experiences/desktop/continuum/) or if I need my program to be able to manipulate other windows such as minimize/maximize them what tools can I use other than winAPI?

Comment: `MFC` and `Windows Template Library` then ? Windows-centric C++ libraries, what other source than Microsoft would care to make them ?

Comment: @Arioch'The well i've tried looking in msdn for tutorials but they refer to winapi. I must be looking in the wrong places.

Comment: You need to learn both the winapi and a cross-platform library. There is no way to avoid it if you want to use C++.

Comment: Windows-centric library would use WinAPI. You cannot "take advantage of being platform-specific" without BEING "platform-specific"
Delphi VCL is told to be good WinAPI wrapper, but even with it you can easily freeze your app if you don't have idea of WinAPI. Also there have to be "greatest common divisor"  between your program and those whose windows you want to control. OS API is that control, nothing else can be assumed granted.

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.*. To me, this questions is open-ended, because you ask about enumerating several different tools, not limited to a *a specific programming problem*, which can be asked here. I guess that is why this question was closed as well.

Comment: Eveyr library has to appeal to some users. That means it should be targeted to some task, some environment or some language. For example Thread Building Blocks is targeted at multithreading. STL and ATL are targeted at C++. As well as QT and Apache Portable Runtime. COM/OLE would be targeted at Windows. And you know, take thin wrapper like FLTK or this wrapper like Fox Toolkit or Qt, they always would play catch-up to native OS API, be it Windows or MacOS or anything. When OS vendor releases "aero" or any new feature, they only start designing. Being on bleeding edge == using native API.

Comment: @Default I asked to ENUMERATE several different tools LIMITED to the conditions I stated above such as 1. preferably C++ 2. must be able to take advantage of windows specific features 3. must be easily portable 4. not necessarily cross-platform. I understand why my first question was closed, it's because I asked for "easier" which is objective and would likely cause debate. But I don't understand why this question is closed too. I'm not asking for a discussion, I'm only asking for a short list of options.

Comment: If we list the questions that can be asked at StackOverflow, they are: - a specific programming problem, - a software algorithm, - software tools commonly used by programmers, - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession. In what category would you put this question?

Comment: @Default "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession". I'm not asking for ALL of the possible answers that can fit my conditions, i'm only asking for whatever can be supplied. (See robert's answer below) And I also believe that the question I presented does not solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. What is there to debate, argue, poll, or discuss about? A list is a list, im not asking for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand, because there is nothing hindering you from using platform specific features even if you use Qt (or any other x-platform framework). You just separate those specific features in different complilation units for the different platforms you wish to support. There' not much more to it than that.

Nominally you define an interface/class in a header file, then you can implement that interface/class in multiple different body files, each one holding the implementation of the specific platform, f.i. Win32/Mac OS X /Linux.

f.i in the header (.h file):

```
class MyXPlatformClass {
public:
   static std::string getMachineName();
}
```

Then you implement this "interface" in the cpp files:

Win32:

```
std::string MyXPlatformClass::getMachineName() {
   char buffer[256]; 
   GetComputerNameA(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
   return buffer;
}
```

Mac OS X (and Linux ?):

```
std::string MyXPlatformClass::getMachineName() {
   char buffer[256]; 
   gethostname(&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
   return buffer;
}
```

This is how cross platform coding is done, and it has nothing to do with the framework you choose to work with. I recommend Qt though, because it is fairly "complete", meaning that it has pretty much all tools required not to bother with platform specific code. But if you need it, you can use the approach above.

Comment: Please explain further. I obviously don't know about this. If I did, I wouldn't be asking.